# New error trying to compile pygame to exe

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, py2exe

I have created a small game for my little boy using Python 3.4 and Pygame in Windows 7. It also works in Python 2.X, with some minor bugs.
Then I tried to create an .exe file using py2exe. I prepared a setup.py file copying the source I found at pygame2exe wiki (http://www.pygame.org/wiki/Pygame2exe?parent=CookBook) also trying to use the suggestions I found in other questions here and in python-forum. What I obtained was the following error:

> C:\Python34>python setup.py install
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "setup.py", line 5, in
>
> ```
> origIsSystemDLL = py2exe.build_exe.isSystemDLL # save the orginal before we edit it
> ```
>
> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'build_exe'

I have read all other posts on stackoverflow on pygame and exe but I haven’t found anything on this type of error on the web, is there anybody that can help me?

PS for those who prefer cx_freeze, I have tried it too, finding different problems and I will prepare soon another question on it

To give you more details, I am adding this new lines:

- if I use the standard setup.py file instead, I have a dist directory with an .exe, but if I launch it I get an error window and in the log I find:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> ```
> File "C:\Python34\lib\tokenize.py", 
>
> line 369, in find_cookie
>
> line_string = line.decode('utf-8')
> ```
>
> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: invalid start byte
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: etc....
>   
>   And the first lines in the cmd are about 16 missing modules

- if I try to use Python 2.6 instead of 3.4 I otain a Microsoft Visual C++ runtime error with the pygame2exe version, and a similar comment in the log if I use the 'short' py2exe version (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Nomi_Animali_1.1p.py", line 100, in 
  basicFont = pygame.font.SysFont("FreeSansBold.ttf", 72)
  File "pygame__init__.pyc", line 70, in **getattr**
  NotImplementedError: font module not available
  (ImportError: DLL load failed: Impossibile trovare il modulo specificato.))

I have tried in all cases to use as font: None, "Arial", "FreeSansBold.ttf"

Comment: I hope you didn't call one of your file (or folder) `py2exe`.

Comment: Hi furas, no, I did not. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just `import py2exe.build_exe` again will work

```
>>> import py2exe
>>> py2exe.build_exe
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'build_exe'
>>> import py2exe.build_exe
>>> py2exe.build_exe
<module 'py2exe.build_exe' from 'C:\\Python34\\lib\\site-packages\\py2exe\\build_exe.py'>
```